# Shared Network folder path - check files recursively in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that takes user input for a folder path. Then it recurs the files and hashes them and what not.

What I need is a way to take input for the path either local folders (C:\somefolder\folder) or shared network folder paths (\\one-of-our-company-servers-address.com\folder). Right now the script fails with network shared folders, but works with local ones.

```
$folder1 =  (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter path to folder")
$hashes1 = Get-ChildItem -Path ($folder1) -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1
```

Comment: please show some examples of what the user enters as network path. Also, show us the error messages you get when _the script fails_

Comment: (\\one-of-our-company-servers-address.com\folder) that is what I enter as a network path to the folder (I can't be more specific) as a local path the user can enter any path to their local machine (the script runs successfully in this case) - there is no error message when running the script. It just freezes.

Comment: Can you actually reach that path?, do you have permisions to go there? can you do this using the servers IP address or NetBios name? does the path have spaces (you're not quoting it) ?

Comment: you have `()` around both your `Read-Host` call and around the `$folder1` variable when you use it. they are NOT needed ... and in some rare occasions can cause problems. i would remove them to simplify your code.

Comment: The location is reachable, I do also have permissions.
Tried to remote the braces - still acting the same way.